# The Outliner doesn't show Parent-Child relations in blender 2.8

Tags: parent, outliner

I have a pretty big scene in blender. In v2.79 the hierarchy looks like this in the *Outliner*:

[image]

However, with 2.80 Beta, it looks like in the screenshot below. The only indicator that we get for "Parent-Child relations" is the one I circled in the screenshot.

[image]

I honestly think that this is messed up. This way it's a lot harder to see / select / interact with the desired objects (for example if I want to select all the objects parented to "_3D_FURNITURE"). I have to check the objects one-by-one to see the relations.

Is there a way to show the hierarchy as in 2.79?

Comment: this is kind of cumbersome to have in the 2.80 and I hope they will address that even in scenes layer it should be visible those hierarchies what is the sense of this collection if they can show properly of the parent-child indicator.

Comment: @royor My guess would be that the collections have a hierarchy they can contain a list of objects and or collections.  Eg an objects child and parent may or may not be part of that collection.  Being able to then expand these objects at different levels in the collection would be a cluster-f.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Child-Parent relations are displayed when the *Outliner* is in the ***Scenes* mode**. This can be selected from the header:

[image]

<sup>A convincing and efficient way of showing simultaneously Collection hierarchies and Parenting hierarchies has been looked for, but hasn't been found yet. I'd say that this is still likely to change before the Beta becomes Stable.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do that simultaneously, one way is to split the outliner window into two (one on top of the other if you have enough screen estate) and show one in layer mode and one in scene mode. Frankly, thinking about this, it will not be possible to show both hirarchies, as you can have different parented relationships across collections I assume.

[image]