# Why can't I parent objects in my .blend?

Tags: objects, parent, outliner

Here's a weird one - I can't seem to create a parent child relationship in my current Blender project.

For example, I want to make 'Cube' a child of the 'ModuleParent' empty. If you take a look at [this linked .blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51142), can you create that relationship?

If so, how? (Have tried ctrl-p, have tried dragging and dropping in Outliner (with shift and ctrl), nowt seems to work)

Thanks in advance for your help.

--Rev

Comment: All of those work fine for me (`Blender 2.80 (sub 43) a1ae04d15a9f`). Have you tried setting *Parent* in *Properties > Object > Relations* with `Cube` selected?

Comment: Yup, so I looked that section up in my objects and - there we are, clear as day, the objects are parented correctly. As it happens, this problem stems from my misunderstanding vis a vis Scenes and View Layer views in the Outliner. Bigger explanation below, hopefully...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Set outliner display mode to Scene**

I wonder if this is the outliner display mode being viewlayer rather than scene as default. Was a source of confusion for me the other day as  parent relationship works, but in viewlayer display doesn't show as hierarchy like we are used to in 2.79 and prior.

In your file cube is a child of another cube that is a child of the empty. Can drag around in outliner after setting display mode to scene and parenting works as in previous versions with drag and drop.

[image]

Comment: You're on the money. I didn't realise that Scene and View Layer modes in Outliner were drastically different. To be honest, I'm still a little confused by the distinctions, but I think I'm starting to pick it up. Thanks for building a .gif for this. In case anybody else as as dense as I am, here's a related Q/A for additional illumination... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127105/the-outliner-doesnt-show-parent-child-relations-in-blender-2-8