# Python: How to highlight invisible object in outliner?

Tags: python, selection-tools, select

Using python, Is it possible just to highlight the object in outliner even if it's hidden in viewport ? i mean without making them visible in viewport first.

Actually i don't need to 'select' them, i just need to get them highlighted in outliner so i know where they are in the structure. Hope that make sense.

Comment: I'm interested in this too, the outliner has received a lot of love recently but the documentation hasn't really followed :) Maybe this can help ? https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-get-selection-objects-list-in-outliner/1184175/6

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127105/the-outliner-doesnt-show-parent-child-relations-in-blender-2-8   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130575/why-cant-i-parent-objects-in-my-blend

Comment: actually has nothing to do with outliner. I'm looking a way in python function to highlight some objects  in outliner even if their visibility or selectable is OFF.

Comment: Apologies was fooled by question title,  question body  _"i just need to get them highlighted in **outliner** so i know where they are"_  and again in comment above,.. all of which appear to refer to the outliner.  Links posted show how to put outliner in hierarchy mode to display _"where they are in structure"_.

Comment: sorry if i'm not too detail. I'm making a python script to dig the object, to search recursively the boolean modifier it uses. For example A use B as cutter (boolean difference), and B itself contains combination of multi boolean: union of D,C,.. as cutter. so on. I need to search all the related objects in this 'nested' boolean. I made a code to search them all, it's working but now final step to highlight them in outliner. since some of them are  hidden/unselectable. To get them highlighted in outliner, i have to turn on all the visiblity and selectable first, so my code will works properly.

Comment: Right now , using python,  i track them down and make them visible or selectable and now  highlight works. But of course now , i have to manually hide them back  , and it's not fun things to do.

Comment: To expand on this, what do you wish to do with them once they are selected ?