# Camera acts like it has a child of constraint, when there is none

Tags: camera, constraints

[image]

My camera acts like it has a child of constraint when it doesn't. It has a track constraint but that shouldn't (and doesn't look like) it affects the position of the camera. It is under the armature in the collection tab but there's no constraint, am I missing something?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130575/why-cant-i-parent-objects-in-my-blend  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127105/the-outliner-doesnt-show-parent-child-relations-in-blender-2-8

Answer (score 1):

Its position in the outliner indicates that it is a child of the armature (possibly, of some bone in the armature.)  Not a child-of-- literally a child.  Select the camera and use a clear parent operation (alt p for me) with keep transformation.